# How do I launch a list view item on click?

Tags: android, listview

My listview                                                                              displays a                                                                           list of user installed apps,                                but How do I get the package name of the clicked item?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView userInstalledApps = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.installed_app_list);

    List<AppList> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
    AppAdapter installedAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
}

private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(new AppList(appName, icon));
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true : false;
}
```

This is what I have tried, but How do I get the packagename?

```
 userInstalledApps.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide your adapter

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla its in the code posted in the question. In oncreate

Comment: I'm talking about AppAdapter

Comment: @AnisuzzamanBabla here https://inducesmile.com/android/android-list-installed-apps-in-device-programmatically/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your code snippet in applist.java file

```
private String name;
String package_name;
Drawable icon;

public AppList(String name, String package_name, Drawable icon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.package_name = package_name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public String getPackage_name() {
    return package_name;
}
```

also change your list java file code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView userInstalledApps = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.installed_app_list);

    final List<AppList> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
    AppAdapter installedAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
    userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            AppList appList = installedApps.get(i);
            Log.e("pacakge name", appList.getPackage_name());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            String package_name = p.applicationInfo.packageName;
            res.add(new AppList(appName, package_name, icon));
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change `AppList` object to also include the package name, and fill it when filling name. Then when user selects item from list, you can get the `AppList` for selected item from the adapter, and get the package name from it.
Basic example;

```
public class AppList { 
private String name; 
Drawable icon; 
String packageName;
public AppList(String name, Drawable icon, String packageName) { 
this.name = name; 
this.icon = icon; 
this.packageName = packageName
} 
.....
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to do that

Comment: I want the list items to return the app name and package name on click

Comment: I added small example

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, let me test it

Comment: ok done, I have modifies my AppList to include all 3. But how do I use them now in my onclicklistener?